# Integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{|t_1|^\alpha} \frac{1}{|t_2|^\alpha} \frac{1}{|t_1-t_2|^\alpha} e^{i\omega (t_1+t_2)} dt_1 dt_2 $

Tags: definite-integrals, asymptotics

For $\alpha>0, \omega>0$, I am curious on the integral
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{|t_1|^\alpha} \frac{1}{|t_2|^\alpha} \frac{1}{|t_1-t_2|^\alpha} e^{i\omega (t_1+t_2)} dt_1 dt_2, $$
where we understood
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty = \lim_{R\to\infty} \int_{-R}^R \int_{-R}^R.$$
I tried Wolfram alpha but it does not give me an answer for a long time. If an exact result is untractable, asymptotic expression for fixed $\alpha$ and large $\omega$ is also appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know whether this problem is still relevant, but the solution can be obtained in closed form.
$$I(a,\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{|t_1|^a} \frac{1}{|t_2|^a} \frac{1}{|t_1-t_2|^a} e^{i\omega (t_1+t_2)} dt_1 dt_2\,; \,a,\omega>0$$
First of all, making substitution $p_{1,2}=\omega \,t_{1,2}$ we extract $\omega$ as a general factor:
$$I(a,\omega)=\omega^{3a-2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{|p_1|^a} \frac{1}{|p_2|^a} \frac{1}{|p_1-p_2|^a} e^{i(p_1+p_2)} dp_1 dp_2$$
Next, we make substitution:
$$x=p_1+p_2 ; \,y=p_1-p_2; \,\Big|\frac{\partial (p_1,p_2)}{\partial (x,y)}\Big|=\frac{1}{2}$$
$$I(a,\omega)=\omega^{3a-2}2^{2a-1}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty  \frac{e^{ix}}{|x^2-y^2|^a|y|^a} dx dy$$ $$=\omega^{3a-2}2^{2a+1}\int_{0}^\infty \int_{0}^\infty  \frac{\cos x}{|x^2-y^2|^ay^a} dx dy$$
$$=\omega^{3a-2}2^{2a+1}\int_{0}^\infty \cos x \,dx\int_{0}^\infty  \frac{dy}{|x^2-y^2|^ay^a}=\omega^{3a-2}2^{2a+1}\int_{0}^\infty \cos x \,dx\,J(x,a)$$
Let's consider
$$J(x,a)=\int_{0}^\infty  \frac{dy}{|x^2-y^2|^a|y|^a}=\int_{0}^x  \frac{dy}{(x^2-y^2)^a\,y^a}+\int_x^\infty  \frac{dy}{(y^2-x^2)^a\,y^a}=J_1+J_2$$
Making change in the first integral $\,y^2=sx^2$ and extracting $x$ as a factor
$$J_1=\frac{x^{1-3a}}{2}\int_0^1\frac{ds}{s^{\frac{a+1}{2}}(1-s)^a}=\frac{x^{1-3a}}{2}B\Big(\frac{1-a}{2};1-a\Big)$$
In the same way making substitution in the second integral
$$J_2=\frac{x^{1-3a}}{2}\int_1^\infty\frac{ds}{s^{\frac{a+1}{2}}(s-1)^a}=\frac{x^{1-3a}}{2}\int_0^\infty\frac{ds}{(1+s)^{\frac{a+1}{2}}s^a}$$
Making another substitution $t=\frac{1}{1+s}$
$$J_2=\frac{x^{1-3a}}{2}\int_0^1\frac{dt}{t^2}t^{\frac{a+1}{2}}\Big(\frac{t}{1-t}\Big)^a=\frac{x^{1-3a}}{2}B\Big(\frac{3a-1}{2};1-a\Big)$$
Taking all together and expressing the beta function in terms of gamma-function
$$I(a,\omega)=\omega^{3a-2}2^{2a+1}\frac{\Gamma(1-a)}{2}\Bigg(\frac{\Gamma\big(\frac{1-a}{2}\big)}{\Gamma\big(\frac{3}{2}(1-a)\big)}+\frac{\Gamma\big(\frac{3a-1}{2}\big)}{\Gamma\big(\frac{1+a}{2}\big)}\Bigg)\int_0^\infty\cos x\,x^{1-3a}dx$$
The whole expression makes sense (and the last integral converges) only for $a\in\big(\frac{1}{3};\frac{2}{3}\Big).$
To evaluate the remaining integral
$$J_3=\int_0^\infty\cos x\,x^{1-3a}dx=\Re\int_0^\infty e^{ix}\,x^{1-3a}dx$$
we go in the complex plane and make the change of the variable $x=it$. Having done that, we also changed the integration path, but it can be shown that the additional integrals (along small and big quarter-circles) wanish for the $a$ in the chosen limits (above).
$$J_3=\Re \,i\int_0^\infty e^{-t}t^{1-3a}e^{\frac{\pi i}{2}(1-3a)}dt=\Gamma(2-3a)\sin\Big(\frac{\pi}{2}(3a-1)\Big)$$
We can further simplify the answer, using the Euler formula $\,\Gamma(x)\Gamma(1-x)=\frac{\pi}{\sin\pi x}$ and noting, for example, that $\frac{1-a}{2}=1-\frac{1+a}{2}$ and $\frac{3a-1}{2}=1-\frac{3}{2}(1-a)$ , etc.

I got the answer that can be, probably, simplified further (please, do it, but check the solution first):
$$I(a,\omega)=\omega^{3a-2}4^a\pi\,\frac{\Gamma(1-a)\Gamma(2-3a)\sin\big(\frac{\pi}{2}(3a-1)\big)}{\Gamma\big(\frac{3}{2}(1-a)\big)\Gamma\big(\frac{1+a}{2}\big)}\Bigg(\frac{1}{\sin\big(\frac{\pi}{2}(1+a)\big)}+\frac{1}{\sin\big(\frac{3\pi}{2}(1-a)\big)}\Bigg)$$